# Dependency conflicts with Poetry

Tags: sockets, flask, dependencies, flask-socketio

I get the following error when I attempt to install/add fxcmpy and make it work with Flask framework. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Using version ^1.2.10 for fxcmpy

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

SolverProblemError

Because no versions of fxcmpy match >1.2.10,<2.0.0
and fxcmpy (1.2.10) depends on python-socketio (4.4), fxcmpy (>=1.2.10,<2.0.0) requires python-socketio (4.4).
And because flask-socketio (5.1.1) depends on python-socketio (>=5.0.2)
and no versions of flask-socketio match >5.1.1,<6.0.0, fxcmpy (>=1.2.10,<2.0.0) is incompatible with Flask-SocketIO (>=5.1.1,<6.0.0).
So, because repl-python3-flask depends on both Flask-SocketIO (^5.1.1) and fxcmpy (^1.2.10), version solving failed.

at /opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
237│             packages = result.packages
238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
240│         except SolveFailure as e:
→ 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
242│
243│         results = dict(
244│             depth_first_search(
245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes

Comment: As the error message states fxcmpy and flask-socketio packages require different version of python-socketio. You can try to clone [fxcmpy repositoy](https://github.com/fxcm/RestAPI) and upgrade its dependency it may work. Or you can find an older version of flask-socketio that has older python-socketio dependency.